# Stokes Number (characteristic length)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, airflow

I am working with a high speed flow that is non-stokesian, but that isn't the issue. There are correction factors for that. I am attempting to figure out what value to use for the "characteristic length". I have glass microspheres in the flow and they are moving towards a sampling probe. This probe has an OD=4 mm and an ID=2 mm. What is the "characteristic length" of the obstacle? I have seen papers calculate stokes numbers with absolutely no obstacle. I am unsure what to use in this situation.

EDIT: Looking at other probes in literature, it looks like the inner diameter is typically used: "A Study of the Effects of Anisokinetic Sampling" by Daniel Rader